# TIdIOHandler.Write procedure is not working from mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm  trying to send a stream from a mobile device (iOS, Android) to TCP  Server. For the server and client side I'm using the Indy components.

The issue happens when I try to send a  stream from a FMX application running in a mobile device. If I run the client code from Windows the client send the stream to the Server App. But I run the same code from a mobile device the stream is not sent.

This is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for the  server and client, which can reproduce the issue.

Server Side . The server  is a *VCL* Application.

```
unit uServer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdContext;

type
  TFrmServer = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    MemoLog: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmServer: TFrmServer;

implementation

uses
  IdGlobal,
  IdIOHandler,
  System.StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrmServer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := 28888;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
  MemoLog.Lines.Add('Running');
end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LHandler  : TIdIOHandler;
  s: string;
  LMemoryStream : TMemoryStream;
  AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
  d : Int64;
begin
  try
    LHandler := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;
    s := LHandler.ReadLn(LF, IdTimeoutDefault, MaxInt);
    AFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create;
    if (s <> '') then
    begin
       if StartsText('<',  s) and EndsText('>',  s)  then
       begin
            TThread.Queue(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                MemoLog.Lines.Add(Format('%s', [s], AFormatSettings));
              end
            );
            LMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
            try
                LHandler.LargeStream := True;
                LHandler.ReadStream(LMemoryStream, -1, False);
                d := LMemoryStream.Size;
                TThread.Queue(nil,
                  procedure
                  begin
                    MemoLog.Lines.Add(Format('Stream Size %d', [d], AFormatSettings));
                  end
                );
            finally
              LMemoryStream.Free;
            end;
       end
       else
         LHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      s := E.Message;
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          MemoLog.Lines.Add(Format('Exception %s', [s], AFormatSettings));
        end
      );
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Client (FMX Application)

```
unit uClient;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, FMX.ScrollBox,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TFrmClient = class(TForm)
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    Button1: TButton;
    MemoLog: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Send;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmClient: TFrmClient;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

type

  TSendThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(ATCPClient : TIdTCPClient); reintroduce;
  end;

procedure TFrmClient.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Send;
end;

procedure TFrmClient.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 try
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 28888;
  IdTCPClient1.Host := '192.168.1.134'; //change this to the ip of the  TCP server.
  IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect();
  MemoLog.Lines.Add('Connected');

  except on E: Exception do
     MemoLog.Lines.Add('Exception ' + E.Message);
 end;
end;

procedure TFrmClient.Send;
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
    TSendThread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
end;

{ TSendThread }

constructor TSendThread.Create(ATCPClient: TIdTCPClient);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FTCPClient := ATCPClient;
end;

procedure TSendThread.Execute;
var
  LStream : TStream;
  d : Int64;
begin
   LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     //Send a text from all the platforms works perfect.
     FTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('<Hello>');
     LStream.Size := 1024;
     LStream.Position := 0;
     d := LStream.Size;
     FTCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
     //this only works from Windows
     FTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(LStream,  d, True);
   finally
     LStream.Free;
   end;
end;

end.
```

The question is, How I can send a stream using the Indy component from a mobile device?.

UPDATE :

Android permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions for network access in the mobile application manifests?

Comment: I just added the permissions used.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the issue, I made a mistake thinking which the data was not send, The stream is sent, but the server can't process the stream because the  `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream` function is not reading correctly the size of the stream. This happens when a -1 value is passed in the `AByteCount` parameter. Then the `TIdIOHandler.ReadInt64` or `TIdIOHandler.ReadInt32` functions are used to read the size of the stream and internally these functions are trying to convert the Endianness of the integer using the `GStack.NetworkToHost` function.

I fixed the issue reading the stream size without convert the endianess.

I replaced this line

```
LHandler.ReadStream(LMemoryStream, -1, False);
```

for this code

```
LHandler.LargeStream := True;
LHandler.ReadBytes(LBytes, SizeOf(Int64), False);
d := BytesToInt64(LBytes);
LHandler.ReadStream(LMemoryStream, d, False);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indy operates the same way on all platforms, so there should be no difference in how a stream is sent or received.

The only problems I see in your code are:

1. a memory leak in the client code when running on Windows
2. an unnecessary call to `InputBuffer.Clear` in the server code

But I don't see anything that would cause the issue you have described. You will have to debug the communications with a debugger and packet sniffer to find out what is going wrong.

The transmitted bytes **should** look like this:

```
3C 48 65 6C 6C 6F 3E 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00
```

Followed by 1024 bytes of random data (since you are not populating the `TMemoryStream` with any meaningful data).

That being said, you don't really need to pass `d` to the `ASize` parameter of `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` in this example.  You could pass `-1` (all data from current `Position`) or `0` (the whole stream) instead.  The default is `0`.

Comment: Thanks Remy for spot the memory leak in the client and the `InputBuffer.Clear` .call (this is just a sample code to show the issue). I' have been struggling with this issue for days, I realy used an android packet sniffer, but only shows the data sent by the `IOHandler.WriteLn` procedure no data is sent via for the  IOHandler.Write procedure when  is used with a stream parameter.

Comment: I assure you that `Write(TStream)` works.  It uses the same `Write(TIdBytes)` overload that `WriteLn()` uses internally. Even if the `TStream` data were not being sent, the stream size would be. So something else has to be going on. Make sure `IOHandler.SendBufferSize` is > 0, `LStream.Size` really is > 0, etc. Use the debugger to step into Indy's source code if you need to.

Comment: I just checked the value of the `IOHandler.SendBufferSize` property and the value  is `32768` also the Stream size is `1024`. Also I debuged all the functions related : `TIdIOHandler.Write` - > `TIdIOHandler.WriteDirect` ........ -> `TIdStackVCLPosix.WSSend` , finally I ended in the call to the `Posix.SysSocket.send` which returns 1024 (the number of bytes written)  however no data is sent.

Comment: @Salvador that is simply not possible. If the OS `send()` accepts the bytes, they WILL be transmitted provided there is an active connection. What makes you think the data is not being transmitted? Have you actually sniffed the network traffic on both ends?

Comment: I just tried with Wireshark and the stream is sent (my bad). The issue was in the server part in the ReadStream call. When  the AByteCount parameter has a -1 value like  `LHandler.ReadStream(LMemoryStream, -1, False);`  The `ReadInt64`  or  `ReadInt32`  functions are used. to read the size of the stream and internally these functions are trying to convert the Endianness of the integer.

Comment: @Salvador as they should be. `Write(TStream)` will write the stream size in network byte order when `AWriteCount` is true, and `ReadStream()` will read the stream size in network byte order when `AByteCount` is -1 and `AReadUntilDisconnect` is False. So, there is no mismatch, unless you have `LargeStream` set differently on each end.